# Instantiate a class inside a function in Java

Tags: java, function, class, inheritance, abstract-class

I'm trying to create a function which fills a 2d array with some objects. My function looks like this:

```
void funcName(Element el){
    container[0][0] = new el(args);
}
```

The only issue here is that Element is an abstract class, and so Java gives me an error when I try to instantiate an object. What I am trying to do is instantiate objects of classes which are built as extension to Element (i.e Class B extends Element). Is there a way to pass those classes as an argument, and have my function create them accordingly?

Comment: You can't instantiate an abstract class. You must instantiate a concrete class that extends from the Abstract class you need. Let me prepare an example for you.

Comment: Yes, but there's _usually_ a cleaner way to do this. More details about your use case would be helpful. (For instance, you could pass a `Supplier<? extends Element>`.)

Answer (score 1):

The abstract class:

```
public abstract class Element {

    public abstract void myMethod();
    
}
```

The concrete class:

```
public class ArrayElement extends Element{

    @Override
    public void myMethod() {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
    }

}
```

The calling must be done in this way:

```
public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Element element = new ArrayElement();
        calculate(element);     
    }
    
    // This syntax will let you use any class that extends from the Element class, since it guarantees that is convertible to the type that you need. Are called generics.
    public static <T extends Element> void calculate(T element){
        element.myMethod();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
static abstract class Element {} 
static class B extends Element {}

static void funcName(Class<? extends Element> cls)
        throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
        IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException,
        NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
    Element[][] container = new Element[1][1];
    container[0][0] = cls.getConstructor().newInstance();
```

and

```
funcName(B.class);
```

Or

```
static void funcName(Supplier<Element> s) {
    Element[][] container = new Element[1][1];
    container[0][0] = s.get();  // is equivalent to `new B()`
}
```

and

```
funcName(B::new);
```